# C# string encoding issue via mocked HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, json, httpresponsemessage

I am trying to test fetching data from a remote API. I setup the HttpClient as follows:

```
HttpClient httpClient = SetupHttpClient((HttpRequestMessage request) =>
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream("API_Data.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, true);
    var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, sr.ReadToEnd());
    response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("UTF-8");
    return Task.FromResult(response);
});
```

The `SetupHttpClient` is not relevant here - what matters is the Response that is delivered, which as you can see is created by creating a StreamReader from a FileStream and reading that Stream into the Response.

Using the Text Visualizer I can see that the file has been successfully read into the Response Stream and all special chars such as new lines, tabs and double quotes appear correctly, as per this screenshot:

[image: Hover_Debug_Input]

On the other end, I fetch the content from the HttpResponseMessage as follows:

```
Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
StreamReader responseReader = null;

if (response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Count > 0)
    responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.First()));
else
    responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, true);

string content = await responseReader.ReadToEndAsync();
return content;
```

Hover debugging the response again at this point shows that the data is still OK:

[image]

The Text Visualizer shows exactly the same as in the 1st screenshot above. Here comes the problem - even though the response content is a string, I can't access the Value property and all the retrieval mechanisms that response.Content offers are via Streams. OK fine, so I get the content via a Stream, however after having been through the Stream, all special chars are now double escaped as you can see here:

[image]
[image]

This means that I now have to un-escape all these special chars in order to be able to use the returned string as json - if I don't un-escape it then the JsonDeserializer chokes when I try to deserialize it. The StreamReader also adds a (single-escaped) double-quote as the first and last char for good measure.

Googling this all I can find are references to using the correct encoding. As such, I ensured that I saved the source file as UTF-8, that I sent 'UTF-8' as the encoding with the HttpResponseMessage (`response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("UTF-8");`), and that when decoding the Response 'UTF-8' was again used as the encoding (`responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.First()));`) - as you can see, this has not achieved the desired effect of obtaining a string which is not double-escaped.

I don't want to have to do a 'manual' un-escaping of all special chars when I get the response string from the Stream - this is a terrible hack, however it feels like the only option at the minute - either that or use reflection to get the content of the `response.Content.Value` property if I detect that `response.Content` is a String - again another hack that I don't want to do.

How can I ensure that when fetching the `response.Content` value via a StreamReader that I don't get double-escaped special chars?

EDIT: For clarity, here is the SetupHttpClient method:

```
public HttpClient SetupHttpClient(Func<HttpRequestMessage, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> response)
{
    var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
    var clientHandlerStub = new HttpDelegatingHandlerStub((request, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        request.SetConfiguration(configuration);
        return response(request);
    });

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandlerStub);
    mockHttpClientFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(httpClient);
    return httpClient;
}
```

and the HttpDelegatingHandlerStub

```
public class HttpDelegatingHandlerStub : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _handlerFunc;
    public HttpDelegatingHandlerStub()
    {
        _handlerFunc = (request, cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }

    public HttpDelegatingHandlerStub(Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> handlerFunc)
    {
        _handlerFunc = handlerFunc;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _handlerFunc(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

EDIT2: A minimal, reproducible example - this requires the following packages - Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Moq:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

using Moq;

namespace StreamReaderEncoding
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static Mock<IHttpClientFactory> mockHttpClientFactory;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            mockHttpClientFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
            string content = @"{
    ""test"": ""true""
}";
            Console.WriteLine($"content before: {content}");

            HttpClient httpClient = SetupHttpClient((HttpRequestMessage request) =>
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.Write(content);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, true);
                var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, sr.ReadToEnd());
                response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("UTF-8");
                return Task.FromResult(response);
            });

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.test.com");

            Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            StreamReader responseReader = null;

            if (response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Count > 0)
                responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.First()));
            else
                responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, true);

            content = await responseReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"content after: {content}");
        }

        static HttpClient SetupHttpClient(Func<HttpRequestMessage, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> response)
        {
            var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
            var clientHandlerStub = new HttpDelegatingHandlerStub((request, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                request.SetConfiguration(configuration);
                return response(request);
            });

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandlerStub);
            mockHttpClientFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(httpClient);
            return httpClient;
        }
    }

    internal class HttpDelegatingHandlerStub : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _handlerFunc;
        public HttpDelegatingHandlerStub()
        {
            _handlerFunc = (request, cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        }

        public HttpDelegatingHandlerStub(Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> handlerFunc)
        {
            _handlerFunc = handlerFunc;
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return _handlerFunc(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Output from the example:

```
content before: {
    "test": "true"
}
content after: "{\r\n    \"test\": \"true\"\r\n}"
```

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] with the code, writing out the text to the console rather than showing it in the debugger - the way that the debugger escapes strings is muddying things significantly. A simple console app which just makes a request, reads the response as a string and then prints it to the console would help massively. (It really *doesn't* help that you've got a mysterious SetupHttpClient method accepting a delegate, which you claim to be irrelevant - but which we have no clue about. If it's not relevant, then it won't be in the minimal example...)

Comment: It's hard to tell from this code, but it looks like your server is encoding the response as JSON, so the output is a JSON encoded string. So, fix that or deserialise on the other end.

Comment: We're still missing a [mcve] - a complete example we can copy/paste/compile/run, without anything extraneous.

Comment: I *suspect* the problem is using `HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse` - that that's taking your JSON and escaping it. I don't want to investigate any further without being able to reproduce the problem easily though...

Comment: @JonSkeet have added minimal reproducible example, thanks for looking at this :)

Comment: @JonSkeet regarding if it is `HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse` doing this, if you break on line 48 of the example and inspect the response.Content property before it is passed through the StreamReader, you'll see that it is not double-escaped, once it goes through the StreamReader it becomes double-escaped - therefore this is happening in the StreamReader *after* it's been received by the HttpResponseMessage...

Comment: No, it's really not. I've created a *genuinely* minimal repro, which is only 9 lines long and makes it pretty clear where the problem is. Writing it up now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Moq... it's all about `HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse()`, which is taking your string and encoding it as JSON.

Here's a rather more minimal example (as a .NET 6 console app; you can either live with it complaining about restoring a target for net461, or retarget it for .NET 4.7.1 or similar and add some project options and using directives; I think it's simpler to leave it targeting .NET 6.)

```cs
using System.Web.Http;

var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.SetConfiguration(new HttpConfiguration());
string json = "{ \"test\": \"true\" }";
Console.WriteLine($"Before: {json}");
var response = request.CreateResponse(json);
string text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"After: {text}");
```

Output:

```cs
Before: { "test": "true" }
After: "{ \"test\": \"true\" }"
```

The thing that I believe is confusing you is that in the debugger you were looking at the `response.Content`, seeing the `Value` in the `ObjectContent<string>` as the string *as you wanted it*, and assumed that that's the data that's going to be written to the response. It's not. That's the data *before* it's formatted.

The simplest way of fixing this is to provide the content of the response as a `StringContent` instead. As that point you don't need *any* dependencies - the code below is a minimal example which prints the same text for "before" and "after":

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
string json = "{ \"test\": \"true\" }";
Console.WriteLine($"Before: {json}");
var response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(json) };
string text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"After: {text}");
```

Of course you may well want to set some other headers on the response, but I believe this proves that it really is the `CreateResponse` method (and its use of `ObjectContent`) that's causing the problem.